# Withings: getting oauth_callback to.. call back?

Tags: oauth, withings

Im working with the `withings` oauth implementation in hopes of retrieving stored values from scales. I can get the request token which I send back in hopes of getting the **userid** and the **oauth_verifier** passed back to my application.

What is happening is that if I pass in a full URL via the **oauth_callback** ( EG "http://some.site.com/myapp.php" ) the withings page displays the results on its page. But if I pass in just a page ( EG "myapp.php" ) withings will append this page name to its site and attempt to pass the parameters there (resulting in a 404). (EG "http://oauth.withings.com/account/myapp.php?oauth_params=..." ).

Other bits:
1. Code is in Perl
2. All **oauth_signature** values are `HMAC_SHA1` signed
3. Any bits passed on the URL are url encoded using `uri_escape`

My questions:
1. Has anyone succeeded in getting data from withings?
2. Has anyone seen and overcome this problem with **oauth_callback**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is to url encode the address.. and then encode it *again* when you use it in the resultant signature and URL that you pass to withings.

I was just encoding it once.